# stop moving a UIButton

Tags: iphone, animation, uibutton

I am moving a UIButton using the

```
animateWithDuration:delay:option:animations:completion
```

method. Now, I want it to stop moving when it passes over a specific point. How do I do that? Any insights appreciated!

Comment: Just so I understand - you want to animate your button from point A to point B, but have it stop when it reaches point C? Why not just animate it from point A to point C in the first place?

Comment: @Mac - Thats because while B is generated randomly, C is fixed, so I won't know everytime when the button moves from A to B, that it WILL pass over C.

Answer (score 0):

use these line in your moving code(button move).

set x and y according to you and give some height and width for a location;

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(yorButton.frame,CGRectMake(6,6,10,10))) {

     //code for stop moving 
}
```

Comment: No offense just curious, But How does this code helps Appster ? Appster may not be using touchesmoved event for animating button.

Comment: oops you are right then also this condition work and need to right in section where he used the moving code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can using the animation stop selector.
In general way it is done like this

```
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(bounce2AnimationStopped)];
```

Now if you are using a block,you can check this how to use the AnimationDidStopSelector
in that.

Thanks

Comment: naah, this won't help. Since Im using block based animation anyway, I can place the end code directly in the block. I want the animation to end prematurely!